# Unable to insert/update data from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am unable to insert and update record through phpmyadmin, where as I am able to do this from php so this could not be the privilege issue,

When ever I try to execute insert, update, delete query from phpmyadmin it says

```
Error in Processing Request  
Error code: 500 Error text: Internal 
Server Error
```

I have already cross checked the privileges for the database user so privileges is not the issue.

Comment: check your apache2 log `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (linux)

Comment: It is a server error, looks like a problem in configuration.

Comment: @Viral I do not have access to error log, s there anythng else you could suggest

Comment: @Jens What should I look in configuration file of phpmyadmin

Comment: @Arpita to find out what is the problem, you have to take a look into the logfiles. If you have no acces to it, you should ask an administrator.

Comment: @Arpita  Which phpMyAdmin version? and did you try a more recent one?

Comment: My version is 4.0.2 and regarding newer version No I dint.